# Angular JS - Display only the field with the highest value from JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON retrieve from database

```
[{"id":1,"firstname":"Alan Cayetano","numbers":2},{"id":2,"firstname":"Bong     Marcos","numbers":0},{"id":3,"firstname":"I Dont Care","numbers":3},{"id":4,"firstname":"toto tata","numbers":0},{"id":5,"firstname":"titi terter","numbers":0},{"id":6,"firstname":"Ian Go","numbers":0}]
```

this is the result when displayed in table result

```
firstname   lastname   numbers
Alan        Cayetano    10
Bong        Marcos      4
Ian         Go          3
What        Ever        0
```

I only want the data with the highest number value
In this case

```
firstname    lastname   numbers
Alan         Cayetano    10
```

This data is dynamically fetch from database

My angular.js

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
    });

    app.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
        //$http.get("http://localhost:8093/voters/voters_angular")
        $http.get("{{ path('vp_president') }}")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.names= JSON.parse(response);
        });
    }]);
    //console.log(names);
</script>
```

Table

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<table class="table">
    //names//

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firsname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>NUm</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td>//x.firstname//</td> 
            <td>//x.lastname//</td>
            <td>//x.numbers//</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
</div>
```

How to achieve this? I am still learning Angular Js
I wonder if Angular's $last filter will work on this

Comment: Why do you need a ngRepeat to show only a single value?

Comment: I am new to Angular and I want to loop first all result then in other part of the template, the highest value should be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as describe

[Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names| orderBy:'-numbers' | limitTo:1">
    <td>//x.id//</td> 
    <td>//x.firstname//</td>
    <td>//x.numbers//</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to find your max in the controller, not in the view.

```
  function findMax(names) {
        var result = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            var name = names[i];
            if (result == null || name.numbers > result.numbers) {
                result = name;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

$scope.name = findMax($scope.names);
```

And in html

```
<tr>
    <td>{{name.firstname}}</td> 
    <td>{{name.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{name.numbers}}</td>
</tr>
```

In AngularJS it's better to pre-sort your data before showing in the view, the ng-repeat creates a watcher for each object it repeat's, in AngularJS the number of watchers is associated with performance if you have many watchers your performance it's worst.

If you don't need the other values to appear, there is no need to create watchers for that values, so it's better to pre-sort the array.

Comment: I got this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: You have to put the findMax($scope.names) in your http response, it's when you have your $scope.names populated

Answer (score 1):

you can do this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:numbers:reverse | limitTo:1">
```

Comment: this result in displaying the lowest value.

Comment: add after numbers ":reverse"

Comment: I will check my JSON file.reverse doesnt work as well

Comment: I found out that the first item in JSON will always show no matter how its value.

Comment: so it should be 'numbers'

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
angular.forEach($scope.names, function (value, key) { //code });
```

With angular foreach you can read row by row in your $scope.names, and use your logic for get the msx value.

When:

key -> is the position (use an alert(key) to see the info)

value -> is a the row of the json. For get data use value.id, value.firstname, etc.